# delete closest class - jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a table formatted html query to bind datas within a div actually. My html query is like,

```
var myTable = <table>
    <tr>
       <td class='deleteMe'>
            <table><tr><td>1</td><td class='close'></td></tr></table>
       </td>
       <td class='deleteMe'>
            <table><tr><td>2</td><td class='close'></td></tr></table>
       </td>
       <td class='deleteMe'>
            <table><tr><td>3</td><td class='close'></td></tr></table>
       <td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

here class `close` contains a `delete` icon. so when I click this delete icon, I can remove the complete `td` like,

```
$(document).on('click', '.close', function () {                
            $(this).closest('table').remove();
        });
```

but what I want here is, I need to get the complete structure except the `deleted one`. that is similar to,

```
var myTable = <table>
    <tr>
       <td class='deleteMe'>
            <table><tr><td>1</td><td class='close'></td></tr></table>
       </td>
       <td class='deleteMe'>
            <table><tr><td>2</td><td class='close'></td></tr></table>
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Why am trying to do like this here is, after binding this `myTable` to my `div` and when I delete `2` from here, its removed but it shows the empty space between `1 and 3`. I dont want this, thats what am trying to get the structure except the deleted one and rebind it to the same div again.

Can anyone help me here, thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click', '.close', function () {                
            $(this).parents('.deleteme').remove();
        });
```

After removal of deleted element do like

```
<script>var data='';
  $(document).on('click', '.close', function () {  data='';            
                $(this).parents('.deleteMe:first').remove();
                $(".deleteMe").each(function(){
                data+=$(this).html();
                });
                });
```

It will store the html of remaining deleteme in var data;

Comment: I need to assign the data(except deleted) to some variable, is it possible

Comment: how can I do that, can u help me

Comment: If there is not gonna be multiple parents with same class, then `parents()` will make jQuery waste a lot of time trying to traverse all parents everytime.

Comment: The gist is this: don't use `parents()` if you don't expect to select multiple parents. :P

Comment: @esailija and if there's multiple parents with the id the code will not do as required since it will remove all the found elements and not just the closest

Answer (score 5):

```
$(this).closest('.deleteMe').remove();
```